# How rebind service in TestHost

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I am preparing environment tests for my application. And I have problem how can i rebind earlier registred services in my startup class?.

I am using TestHost in my tests and this is how looks my base class

```
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TestServer _server;

    public IntegrationTestBase()
    {
        var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

        _server = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
    }

    public HttpClient CreateClient()
    {
        return _server.CreateClient();
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        _server.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've been handling overriding the registration for integration tests is:

Make the ConfigureServices method on your Startup class virtual.
Create a derived class of Startup: e.g: IntegrationTestStartup
Override ConfigureService like:

```
override ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection s) 
{
    base.ConfigureServices(s);
    s.AddSingleton<IService, IMockService>();
}
```

Since the last registration you make of a service is the one provided by the DI container when a constructor injection happens, this works well.

In case you depend on `IEnumerable<IService>`, all components registered for that service will be resolved.

If you can't make your ConfigureServices from the Startup class virtual I assume using `new` would do the job since the WebHostBuilder creates an instance of the type passed to it.

Now you can build your WebHostBuilder with:

```
var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseStartup<IntegrationTestStartup>();
```

Does this help or could you be more specific what kind of 'rebind' do you need?